# Android line chart using MPChart Android lines are mixing and not showing true according to value

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, linechart

I have developed line chart using MpChartAndroid. There are 3 lines. But my first line has much more values than other lines. But graph not showing lines truly.

[image]

You can see first line has value 20 920 000, second 215 378, third 11 300. But this graph is not true. In graph first and second lines height almost the same.How to make this graph nice.Any idea to show lines much more reliable

```
yVals1 = new ArrayList<>();
yVals2 = new ArrayList<>();
yVals3 = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < amountByDateList.size(); i++) {
    yVals1.add(new Entry(i, amountByDateList.get(i).getPurchases()));
}

for (int i = 0; i < amountByDateList.size(); i++) {
    yVals2.add(new Entry(i, amountByDateList.get(i).getBonuses()));
}

for (int i = 0; i < amountByDateList.size(); i++) {
    yVals3.add(new Entry(i, amountByDateList.get(i).getWriteOff()));
}

List<String> xValList = new LinkedList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < amountByDateList.size(); i++) {
    xValList.add(amountByDateList.get(i).getChequeDate());
}


mLineChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
mLineChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
mLineChart.setDragDecelerationFrictionCoef(0.9f);
mLineChart.setDragEnabled(true);
mLineChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
mLineChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
mLineChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
mLineChart.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(false);
mLineChart.setPinchZoom(true);
mLineChart.setAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled(true);
mLineChart.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
mLineChart.animateY(1000);
mLineChart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(1);
mLineChart.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
mLineChart.getRenderer().getPaintRender().setShadowLayer(10, 0, 20, getColorWithAlpha(Color.GRAY, 0.1f));
mLineChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
mLineChart.invalidate();

XAxis xAxis = mLineChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setTextSize(11f);
xAxis.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.line_chart_color));
xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
xAxis.setGranularity(1);
xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new ClaimsXAxisValueFormatter(xValList));
xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(-70);

YAxis leftAxis = mLineChart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.setTextColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
leftAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
leftAxis.setEnabled(false);

YAxis rightAxis = mLineChart.getAxisRight();
rightAxis.setTextColor(Color.RED);
rightAxis.setAxisMinimum(0);
rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
rightAxis.setEnabled(false);
rightAxis.setDrawZeroLine(false);
rightAxis.setGranularityEnabled(false);

mLineChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);


LineDataSet set1, set2, set3;


set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals1, "");
set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
set1.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.shopping_amount_color));
set1.setCircleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.shopping_amount_color));
set1.setLineWidth(4f);
set1.setCircleRadius(1f);
set1.setFillAlpha(60);
set1.setFillColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.shopping_amount_color));
set1.setHighLightColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.shopping_amount_color));
set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);


set2 = new LineDataSet(yVals2, "");
set2.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
set2.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.filled_up_rewards_color));
set2.setLineWidth(4f);
set2.setCircleRadius(1f);
set2.setFillAlpha(60);
set2.setFillColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.filled_up_rewards_color));
set2.setDrawCircleHole(false);
set2.setCircleColor(getColorWithAlpha(getResources().getColor(R.color.filled_up_rewards_color), 0.4f));
set2.setHighLightColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.filled_up_rewards_color));


set3 = new LineDataSet(yVals3, "");
set3.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
set3.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.write_off_rewards_color));
set3.setLineWidth(4f);
set3.setCircleRadius(1f);
set3.setFillAlpha(60);
set3.setFillColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.write_off_rewards_color));
set3.setDrawCircleHole(false);
set3.setCircleColor(getColorWithAlpha(getResources().getColor(R.color.write_off_rewards_color), 0.4f));
set3.setHighLightColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.write_off_rewards_color));

set1.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
set2.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
set3.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);

LineData data = new LineData(set3, set2, set1);

data.setValueTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

mLineChart.clear();

if (null != mLineChart.getLineData())
    mLineChart.getLineData().clearValues();
mLineChart.setData(data);
mLineChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
mLineChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here is the formatter:

```
public static class ClaimsXAxisValueFormatter extends ValueFormatter {

    List<String> datesList;

    public ClaimsXAxisValueFormatter(List<String> arrayOfDates) {
        this.datesList = arrayOfDates;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAxisLabel(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        int index = Math.round(value);

        if (index < 0 || index >= datesList.size() || index != (int) value)
            return "";
        return datesList.get((int) value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide us with some code.

Comment: @Lilya Here is the code,I edited my post.

Comment: You set a custom ```xAxis.setValueFormatter(new ClaimsXAxisValueFormatter(xValList));```. Please, show the code